# PhpStorm - close tabs without a dialog box

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to close a Debug tab but, as it's connected to a server with xdebug, I'm getting a dialog box with:

```
Do you want to disconnect from the process <name of xdebug process>?
```

I can't see a config to disable these dialog boxes. Anyone know of a way of disabling them?

Comment: hmmm ... related to **[this question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207699045-Use-case-for-Terminate-process-after-disconnect-)** i posted today ? If it is, this kind of stuff is driving me nuts.

Comment: well well well ... the bug now has a 'fixed in build' number. Your next EAP should fix that annoying `feature`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [**six years old open issue**](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-54188) at Jetbrains.